# Exception warning of possible Data loss or corruption

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm not sure why I am receiving this message. All I have in my WPF app is `SpeechRecognitionEngine` and `SpeechSynthesizer`, and when I click 'X' to close the app, the `Application.Current.Shutdown(0)` gets called after I display a message to the user via TextBlock.

What could possiby be causing this? It's not like I'm doing anything out of the ordinary. I've made this exact same type of app before with the same code, why is this only happening now?

> RaceOnRCWCleanup was detected Message: An attempt has been made to
>   free an RCW that is in use.   The RCW is in use on the active thread
>   or another thread.   Attempting to free an in-use RCW can cause
>   corruption or data loss.

Comment: I am assuming that the things it says are still in use, are the Speech engines. But I am disposing of them before application shitdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I *was* disposing of the engines, but for some reason I commented out the `.Dispose()` calls and forgot to uncomment them again.

Idiot. lol